# UltraGrid modify new row columns

Tags: vb.net, button, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a `UltraGrid` in which you can add a row by filling informations in the blank row on the top. I want to modify the row so that I don't see the button at the end like this (At the end of the grey line) :

[image]

I can't find where to modify this row only. Any Idea ?

Comment: I don't know if you can consider this an answer, so I post this as comment. You tell me. There is an event called InitializeTemplateAddRow that is designed to customize the TemplateAddRow (this is the name of that row). Despite the fact that a cell has a Hidden property I was not able to hide a particular cell of the TemplateAddRow without also hiding the Whole column, but you could easily disable it setting `e.TemplateAddRow.Cells["Key"].Activation = Activation.Disabled;`

Comment: @Steve Works perfectly. Can you put it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an event called `InitializeTemplateAddRow` that is designed to customize the `TemplateAddRow` (this is the name of that row).
Despite the fact that a cell has a `Hidden` property I was not able to hide a particular cell of the TemplateAddRow without also hiding the whole column, but you could easily disable a particular cell with this code inside the event handler:

```
Imports Infragistics.Shared
Imports Infragistics.Win
Imports Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid

Private Sub UltraGrid1_InitializeTemplateAddRow(ByVal sender As Object, _
     ByVal e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeTemplateAddRowEventArgs) _
     Handles UltraGrid1.InitializeTemplateAddRow
    ' Initialize the template add-row. You can set the default values for the cells
    ' in the add-row. When the user adds a new row through the template add-row, the
    ' new row will be initialized with these default values. 

    ' e.TemplateAddRow.Cells(0).Value = -1

    ' or totally disable the cells that that you don't want to use (e.g buttons like cells)

     e.TemplateAddRow.Cells["Key"].Activation = Activation.Disabled
End Sub
```